# Can I combine these two lines into a single line?

Tags: python

Here is my beginning code for a linked list in Python:

```
class List:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.next = None

class Node:

    def __init__(self, data, reference = None):
        self.data = data
        self.reference = reference


if __name__ == '__main__':

    linked_list = List()
    linked_list.head = Node(15)
```

My question is, is it possible to combine the two lines in the main into a single line?

For example something such as, (I know this dosn't work)..

```
linked_list = List(self.head = Node(15))
```

Comment: There's something strange about this; if `head` is a node, what is `next`?

Comment: The reference to the next node in the linked list. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/

Comment: But if `head` and `next` are both nodes, then you have pointers to two nodes, not one. That's not how a linked list works! Notice in the Python example from your link, the `LinkedList` class has a `head` and no `next` attribute.

Comment: @kaya3 I don't have a next node. Don't worry about it, someone answered the question for me.

Comment: @DMellon _I don't have a next node._ What is the `next` variable for, then?

Comment: @AMC don't worry about it. A couple other people were able to help me with answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it an a argument in the init:

```
class List:

def __init__(self, head=None):
    self.head = head
    self.next = None
```

Then provide it as an argument:

```
linked_list = List(head = Node(15))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the head node into the constructor on your List class.

```
class List:

    def __init__(self, head):
        self.head = head
        self.next = None

class Node:

    def __init__(self, data, reference = None):
        self.data = data
        self.reference = reference


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Linked_List = List(head=Node(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an assignment expression in Python 3.8+:

```
(Linked_List := List()).head = Node(15)
```